# Problems with countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I'm making a countdown timer, to count for special event. Code is running ok, but it's count wrong by one day. I think that code don't take the h value from date but I don't know how to make it work. I think it's wrong by few hours. My local time is `UTC+01:00`.

```
var eventDay = new Date("Feb 30, 2019 10:00:00").getTime();
var distance = setInterval(function () {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = eventDay - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var sec = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days;
    document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
    document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = sec;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: One thing you can do to find the problem easier is extract the multiple `(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)` into a variable.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the code because the variable names aren't English

Comment: I suggest using moment.js and `diff` method. It's much more powerful.

Comment: Just changed language into english so it might be easier to read.

Comment: Your Code is correct, but eventDay is not a valid Date. February has only 28 days. Check http://jsfiddle.net/6ox2jgk0/ and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=days+until+Feb+27,+2019+10:00:00+PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you have is in this line

```
var godziny = Math.floor((pozostalyCzas % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

you should change it to this

```
var godziny = Math.floor((pozostalyCzas % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. For correct hrs, **(1000 * 60 * 60)** should be used instead of (1000 * 60 * 60 *24), as hrs calculation is wrong, (currently hours are calculated with days calculation)
2. Add +1 for missing day, as the calculation excludes both start and end date

```js
var eventDay = new Date("Feb 28, 2019 10:00:00").getTime();
var distance = setInterval(function(){
var now = new Date().getTime();
var distance = eventDay - now;
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + 1;
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var sec = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days;
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = sec;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="days"></span>d
<span id="hours"></span>h
<span id="minutes"></span>m
<span id="sec"></span>s
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JwxNRg

Comment: @Buszek, I have provided same answer first and provided solution for the second issue for days as well,